# Enabling diagnostics of Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, caching, redis, diagnostics, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to enable diagnostics for Azure Redis Cache. Both redis and storage account are in same region (Us-West).

According to [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-how-to-monitor/#enable-cache-diagnostics) it should work.

After selecting storage account I am getting below generic error.
Any idea how to investigate further or where to report?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage account you are trying to map should support table. You can check the error by visiting to Redis cache.

Operations >> Events chart >> microsoft.insights/diagnosticSettings/write

```
statusCode:BadRequest serviceRequestId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 statusMessage:{"Code":"BadRequest","Message":"The storage account 'xxxxstorage' of type 'Standard_ZRS' doesn't support table service."}
```

Comment: Here is how I got to same error details (on portal.azure.com): select your redis service -> settings -> audit log -> select error. According to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-introduction/#introducing-the-azure-storage-services ZRS does not support table storage so I had to create new LRS storage account. After that tried to enable diagnostics and it worked.